# Adding a reference to existing active record and adding belongs_to, breaks code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have added a reference to an existing model:

```
def change
   add_reference :price_change_requests, :price_reminder, foreign_key:true
end
```

and then add a belongs to relationship to it:

`belongs_to :price_reminder`

and added the respective:

```
class PriceReminder < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :price_change_requests
end
```

But now my code breaks when it runs. 
However, if I comment out the `#belongs_to :price_reminder`

The code works again

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you post the exact error?

Comment: Define "my code breaks" --> do you have failing tests? pages that do not render? specific errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad! forgot to add:

`optional: true` after `belongs_to`

So in full: `belongs_to :price_reminder, optional: true`